# How do I modify the camshiftdemo.cpp sample program to reduce fps, height/width, and range of samples?

Tags: opencv

I am experimenting with the following code on the raspberry pi:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp?rev=4234

and I would like to do the recommendations from this thread:

[Getting better performance using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622672/opencv-better-performance)

Specifically, how do I perform #1 - #4 in the link above?

Looking at this site:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-videocapture-set

I have attempted to do the following:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
cout << "width = " << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << endl;
cout << "height = " << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << endl;
```

However the output always says 640 and 480 for width and height. Am I missing something big here?

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1

Comment: 1. : you're setting CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH twice  2.: not every capture driver implements all those flags. sadly it seems, you can't set the frame size on your raspi this way . if 640x480 is more, than you want to chew, try to resize() or pyDown() your image

Comment: You are correct. I changed the CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH to CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT and everything worked.  I would have given you points but you added a comment.  If you go ahead and answer it I can mark it as correct.